# Can't retrieve data from JSON in Javascript. The json is passed from php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem and i search for a solution, but i can't find it. I have this Json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Pippo (74)",
        "price": "1",
        "latitudine": "10.32562",
        "longitudine": "44.8003686"
    },
    {
        "name": "pluto",
        "price": "2",
        "latitudine": "10.32562",
        "longitudine": "44.8003686"
    }
 ]
```

I want retrieve data from the Json (named msg):

```
num = msg.length;
document.write (num);
document.write (msg[0].name);
```

But it don't work! Can you help me?

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: what's not working exactly, looks fine to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrNQOX

Comment: "But it don't work" - According to @Pabs123 it does, and the codepen examples shows it does. What have you left out which could cause the issue?

Comment: sounds like your json object isn't making it from your PHP to your JS code, because there's nothing wrong with your JS above. better post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this parse json.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
var output = jQuery.parseJSON( '[
{
    "name": "Pippo (74)",
    "price": "1",
    "latitudine": "10.32562",
    "longitudine": "44.8003686"
},
{
    "name": "pluto",
    "price": "2",
    "latitudine": "10.32562",
    "longitudine": "44.8003686"
}]' );

var list = output.data;


$.each(list,function(i,item){
    console.log(item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var parsedMsg = JSON.parse(msg);` to transform to a pure JS object. Then run your script. You also have a typo in 'length'

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark here, but guessing your JSON needs to be parsed:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
var parsedMsg = JSON.parse(msg);
```

then you can do whatever you like with the data:

```
num = parsedMsg.length;
console.log(num);
console.log(parsedMsg[0].name);
```